# Query optimization of a query involving two tables with a join and sort

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

Could not come up with the best title to elaborately describe the problem.
I have two tables `core_question` and `core_team_worker`.

`core_question` has two columns `id int4` and `team_id int4`.

`core_team_worker` has three columns `id int4`, `worker_id int4`, `team_id int4`.

So basically using this `core_team_worker` a many to many relationship between workers and teams can be defined.

Now I have the following query that I need to optimize, it needs to pull one qualifying question in the order received for the specified worker.

```sql
select q.id
from core_question q
join core_team_worker tw on tw.team_id = q.team_id
where tw.worker_id = 18  -- this is where I put the worker id, let's say 18 for example.
order by q.team_id asc, q.id asc
limit 1;
```

Now with 1.6 million records I get a 830 ms on that query.
I have the following databases indices.

I have b-tree indices on primary keys and foreign keys `id, team_id` for core_question and `id, team_id, worker_id` for core_team_worker. In addition to this I created a multi-column index for core_question to optimize this query which works just fine:

```sql
select q.id from core_question q
where q.team_id = 4
order by q.team_id asc, q.id asc
limit 1;
```

Here's the code for multi-column index

```sql
create index core_question_team_id_idx on core_question (team_id asc nulls last, id asc nulls last);
```

Now if I remove the `order by` or the filter on the `worker_id = 18` I get 1ms response time which is perfect. If I could create an index involving both tables, something like `(team_id, worker_id, question_id)` that would help with this query but I understand such index is not possible.

I spent quite some time trying to optimize this query but I still can't get anywhere. How would optimize this query?

Here's the explain analyze result:

```
Limit  (cost=0.57..0.69 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=486.687..486.689 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..53378.10 rows=473106 width=8) (actual time=486.686..486.686 rows=1 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (q.team_id = tw.team_id)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1130118
        ->  Index Only Scan using core_question_team_id_idx on core_question q  (cost=0.43..28924.18 rows=1630117 width=8) (actual time=0.022..150.151 rows=1130119 loops=1)
              Heap Fetches: 0
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.15..2.17 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=1130119)
              ->  Index Scan using core_team_worker_worker_id_823a9ecc on core_team_worker tw  (cost=0.15..2.17 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (worker_id = 18)
Planning Time: 0.374 ms
Execution Time: 486.723 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have very few rows that match the conditions, your execution plan is quite reasonable.  You can try:

```
select q.id
from core_question q join
     core_team_worker tw
     on tw.team_id = q.team_id
where tw.worker_id = 18  -- this is where I put the worker id, let's say 18 for example.
order by q.team_id asc, q.id asc
limit 1;
```

I would suggest the following indexes:

- `core_team_worker(worker_id, team_id)`
- `core_team(team_id)`.

I don't think there is a way to *generally* avoid an outer sort.  But, if there is only one record per worker, then phrasing the query as:

```
select q.id
from core_question q join
     core_team_worker tw
     on tw.team_id = q.team_id
where exists (select 1
              from core_team_worker tw
              where t2.team_id = q.team_id and
                    tw.worker_id = 18 
             )
order by q.team_id asc, q.id asc
limit 1;
```

Then this is can use indexes on `core_team_worker(team_id, worker_id)` and `core_question(team_id, id)`.  But this will probably turn back into your plan.

Comment: @Peyman . . . Did the first version change the execution plan?

Comment: it gave the same exact plan.

Comment: @Peyman . . . Very interesting.  It is working hard to avoid an explicit sort.